После обновления драйверов на ноутбуке Lenovo Legion 5 3060 появилось два экрана
Всегда пользовался только видеокартой зеленых, то есть не переключался между интегрированной и дискретной.
Скорее всего после обновления дров видюхи появился второй экран на ноуте

И теперь видюха показывает как "Только второй экран", в чем я вижу проблему.
На пример, не могу настроить яркость в панельке:

Так же слетает настройка насыщености из панели управления Nvidia при переключении на интегрированную.

Боюсь что в скорем времени найду ряд других проблем.

Как можно насильно задать так, чтобы "Только экран компьютера" была дискретная видеокарта?
